# In Classic ASP, how do I reference a variable based on a string?

Tags: asp-classic

I have many constant variables for example:

Const Total_US_Price = "100"

However, in my code, I am pulling a string "Total_US_Price". I want to replace my string with the value of the Const variable.

How do I do that? How do I change "Total_US_Price" to return "100" (both being strings)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use the eval() function...

http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/QuickRef/eval.html

EDIT: I hope you're not pulling these strings from the client side (query string, POSTed form values, or cookies) or else you are opening yourself up for a world of hurt.  Someone could inject whatever strings they wanted and it will get executed on your web server.

Comment: Eval should be avoided where ever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you exactly mean with 'pulling a string' but please don't abuse eval. Use a lookup table for lookup values.

```
set x = createobject("scripting.dictionary")    
x("total_us_price") = 100
price = x("total_us_price")
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use the "CInt " function.

[VBScript CInt Function](http://www.w3schools.com/VBScript/func_cint.asp) explained and usage.

Comment: that doesn't really help his problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done other than by **executing code dynamically**, using either Eval() to get the value directly, or Execute() to get it by side-effect.

Specifically:

```
MyVarName = "Total_US_Price"
Value100 = Eval(MyVarName)
' Or...
Exectute("Value100 = " + MyVarName)
```

The Eval is more practical, but less flexible...